# Magento 2 - Possible to override third party modules system.xml

Tags: magento, magento2

I am sick of having poor quality modules add useless tabs to the admin menu configuration page, Is it possible to override their modules system.xml (installed via composer) to my own custom system.xml for each of their modules.

I have tried this in my di.xml for a custom module :

```
<preference for="Amasty\base\etc\adminhtml\system" type="Many\Custom\base\etc\adminhtml\system" />
```

which does not work. Is it possible to over ride such a file?

Magento 2.2.4

Edit: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/85295 "You can not override system.xml files"

Comment: This absolutely annoys me. I feel like every extension developer feels like they have to have their own tab rather than organizing things logically in the existing config sections. Did you happen to find a solution?